# Approximating definite integral $\int_0^T e^{-t^2} \sin(wt)dt$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I have the following integral: $\int_0^T e^{-t^2} \sin(wt)dt$ for a finite $T$. I know how it approximately looks but it has no analytic solution. Is there a known approximation for this that I can use to further understand this integral?

Thanks.

Comment: Best approximation is going to depend on T and w.  Can you say for example that $wT \ll 1$?

Comment: I would suggest using the Mclaurin series expansion of the integrand ($e^{-t^2}\sin(\omega t)$). A series is trivial to analytically integrate, and enough terms can be computed to give any level of accuracy.

Comment: Filon-Trapezoidal rule would be one way, anyway, if you know a special case it would be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

I have written a simple Python script using Scipy library to compute this integral numerically.

```
from scipy.integrate import quad
from math import exp, sin
def integrand(x, w):
    return exp(-(x**2))*(sin(w*x))

w = 0.5
t = 1
I = quad(integrand, 0, t, args=(w))
print I
```

You can specify $\omega$ and $T$ for this sort of quadrature. The integrand function returns the function with the specified arguments. $I$ variable contains a tuple as a result of $quad$ function, with the first element holding the estimated value of the integral and the second element holding an upper bound on the error. One sample result would be `(0.2398391635628982, 2.1289501889507458e-12)`.
Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

You may exploit the fact that:
$$ \int_{0}^{+\infty}e^{-t^2}\sin(wt)\,dt = F\left(\frac{w}{2}\right) \tag{1}$$
where $F$ is the [Dawson function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DawsonsIntegral.html), admitting a rather nice continued fraction representation.

The incomplete integral is given by:

$$ \int_{0}^{T}e^{-t^2}\sin(wt)\,dt = \frac{1}{4} e^{-\frac{w^2}{4}} \sqrt{\pi } \left(-i\, \text{Erf}\left(T-\frac{i w}{2}\right)+i\, \text{Erf}\left(T+\frac{i w}{2}\right)+2 \text{Erfi}\left(\frac{w}{2}\right)\right)$$
and both $\text{Erf}$ and $\text{Erfi}$ have nice continued fraction representations.